# How to set gridview first three columns have got 6 elements and other have got 5 elements

Tags: android

In gridview I want set the first 3 columns have got 6 element and other have got 5 elements, how can I set it?

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grdButtons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: I think for this you have to use GridLayout.

Comment: jap but how can i set in greadview :)

Comment: you can't grid view's rows/column is always equal, your best option is Gridlayout as @Haresh mentioned

Comment: How to use GridLayout please see example here : http://androidexample.com/Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=75&aaid=99